# Почему не полностью передается текст русский в datagramSocket java?

Tags: java

Захотелось посмотреть как всё таки просто сделать на java multicast чат. ну как просто, не нужно опции для сокета задавать, как это делается в си. в общем появилась проблема. английский текст он нормально отображает, а русский, после пробела перестает правильно отображать. вот код.
Multi.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Multi {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {

        final int port = 6789;
        InetAddress group;
        try {
                group = InetAddress.getByName ( "228.5.6.7" );
        } catch ( UnknownHostException e ) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            MulticastSocket s = new MulticastSocket ( port );
            s.joinGroup ( group );

            Reader r = new Reader ( s );
            r.start ( );

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( System.in ) );

            while ( true ) {
                byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
                String msg = reader.readLine ( );   
                if ( msg.equals ( "/quit" ) ) break;
                DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket ( msg.getBytes ( ), msg.length ( ), group, port );
                s.send ( datagramPacket );
            }

            s.leaveGroup ( group );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

и вот код reader.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Reader extends Thread {
    private MulticastSocket multiSocket;

    public Reader ( MulticastSocket s ) {
        multiSocket = s;
    }

    public void run ( ) {
        while ( true ) {
            byte[] data = new byte[1000];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket ( data, data.length );
            try {
                multiSocket.receive ( packet );
                System.out.println ( new String ( data ) );
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка здесь

> ```
> DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), msg.length(), group, port);
>                                                                        ^^^^^^
> ```

String.length() возвращает длина строки в **символах**, а передаете вы **байты**

Должно быть так

```
byte[] bytes = msg.getBytes();
DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length(), group, port);
```

и при чтении нужно указывать количество прочитанных байт

```
System.out.println(new String(data, 0, packet.getLength()));
```

Comment: Еще хорошо бы жестко прописывать кодировку в `getBytes(encode)`, иначе будет браться дефолтное значением кодировки, которое может отличаться в JVM респондентов